# QGIS 3: How to iterate in a QgsPrintLayer with pyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, print-composer

I'm looking for a way to iterate through items from a composer in QGIS 3, with pyQgis.

First I create a QgsPrintLayout and add it to the layouts manager in my project.

```
    self.newLayout = QgsPrintLayout(projet)
    self.newLayout.initializeDefaults()
    manager.addLayout(self.newLayout)
```

Then I load a template to populate the QgsPrintLayout

```
    doc=QtXml.QDomDocument()
    doc.setContent(file1, False)
    self.newLayout.loadFromTemplate(doc,QgsReadWriteContext())
```

And I want a list of all the QgsPrintLayout items:

```
    labels = [item for item in self.newLayout.layoutItems()\
    if item.type() == QgsComposerItem.ComposerLabel]  ...
```

But Qgis answers:

```
    labels = [item for item in self.newLayout.layoutItems()\
    AttributeError: 'QgsPrintLayout' object has no attribute 'layoutItems'
```

But in doc for QgsLayout (from which QgsPrintLayout takes a part of its methods), I can read:

> void  layoutItems (QList< T *> &itemList) const

> Returns a list of layout items of a specific type. More...

And I really can't find another Public Member function to list all items from a QgsPrintLayer.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs also state that the `layoutItems()` method is not available in Python bindings, but you can use the inherited method `.items()` which comes all the way from the `QGraphicsScene` base class.

So you could do:

```
layout_items = [i for i in self.newLayout.items()]
print(layout_items)
```

If you are trying to access just the label items, `QgsComposerItem.ComposerLabel` is from the 2.18 API. Instead, you should do something like:

```
label_items = [j for j in self.newLayout.items() if isinstance(j, QgsLayoutItemLabel)]
print(label_items)
```

You could also set the id of a `QgsLayoutItem` with the `setId()` method then retrieve it directly with:

```
self.newLayout.itemById('IdString')
```

Where 'IdString' is whatever id you assigned to your item.

Comment: Thank you very much, using .items() and QgsLayoutItemLabel works perfectly! And now I know I can click on the method name in QGIS doc to see if it's available in the python bindings! ;-)

Comment: @V Damoy, you're welcome- glad it's working.